# How to get all unmerged commits for project in gerrit REST API?

Tags: python, git, rest, gerrit

Hi i was trying to get all commits from specific repository using Gerrit REST API and python which are unmrged (they are active). Can someone help me how to do it? EXAMPLE project: TEST/Python/calcapp
Thanks for help!